# Array Iteration - If Specific, do an If function

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

```
MyArray = Array("Jap", "Mcdonalds", "Chinese", "Pasta")
```

I am trying to do an IF function IF MyArray is on array 'Chinese' however when I do

```
If MyArray("Jap") Then ....
```

it comes up with an error. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: MyArray(0) is "Jap", MyArray(1) is "Mcdonalds" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the array:

```
MyArray = Array("Jap", "Mcdonalds", "Chinese", "Pasta")

for i = lbound(MyArray) to UBound(MyArray)
   if MyArray(i) = "Jap" then
      'do whatever
   End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this, here is one.

```
Sub x()

Dim MyArray, i As Long

MyArray = Array("Jap", "Mcdonalds", "Chinese", "Pasta")

For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
    If MyArray(i) = "Jap" Then
        'do whatever
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test if an item is "in" an array *(of one dimension)*, you can use `Filter()`:

```
Sub dural()
    MyArray = Array("alpha", "beta", "gamma")
    x = Filter(MyArray, "alpha")
    y = Filter(MyArray, "junk")
    MsgBox UBound(x) & vbCrLf & UBound(y)
End Sub
```

[image]

No Loop is required.

Answer (score 0):

Some other ways to avoid looping

```
Sub NoLoop1()
   CMyArray = Array("Jap", "Mcdonalds", "Chinese", "Pasta")
    If Not IsError(Application.Match("Jap", MyArray,0))  
        ‘ your code
    End If
End Sub

Sub NoLoop2()
   CMyArray = Array("Jap", "Mcdonalds", "Chinese", "Pasta")
    If Instr("-" & Join(MyArray, "-") & "-", "-Jap-") > 0 Then 
        ‘ your code
    End If
End Sub
```